# VBA RBG - "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property argument"

Tags: vba, excel, rgb

I know there are other questions which deal with the "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment", but none which deal with this error being generated on a basic line assigning an RGB colour to a cell interior.

This error is generating on line 6 of the below.  I don't understand how this is possible, as RGB clearly has three arguments.

The only thing I can think of is that, earlier today, I wrote a macro in a different (now closed spreadsheet), where I used the initials "rgb" as a variant name.  I know that, in R, it's possible to redefine a base function accidentally by replacing it with a UDF, and I'm wondering whether perhaps I've now unwittingly changed "rgb" to be something other than the function in the VBA base code.  But that doesn't sound plausible - I've never heard of that happening in VBA, and it's more of a "for dummies" type language which I wouldn't have thought would give users that optionality.

**EDIT** Yes - this issue is resolved by changing the name of the macro, which is a stupid error.  However, I would point out that this error is also happening in a different subroutine, which I have not named in such a stupid fashion.  I will need to investigate why it's happening in that sub too.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RGB()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("G20").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 51, 204)
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Sub` is *named* RGB. Just change it to something else.

Comment: Is it resolved with Comintern's comment  ?

Comment: To add to @Comintern's response, your own RGB sub has no arguments and you are trying to shove in three. Change your sub to RgB and see how the RGB function below changes.

Comment: To sum up the comments so far, change your `Sub` name from `RGB` to `SetInteriorColor` and watch magic happen.

Comment: I take offense at "for dummies type language". Understanding how member hiding and identifier resolution works in this dummy language should be simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the comments haven't explained it fully.. you state in your question:

> earlier today, I wrote a macro in a different (now closed
>   spreadsheet), where I used the initials "rgb" as a variant name.

However, in the example you provide, you've actually called the Subroutine you're calling RGB as well. ***This*** is the cause of the issue. Renaming it would fix it but while I'm here I can share with you some other points:

---

This would work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Set_G20_RGB()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")   ' should really be Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("G20").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 51, 204)
End Sub
```

---

However, to make it a little more useful, you might want to use something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Set_RGB(clr_rng As Range, red_value As Integer, grn_value As Integer, blu_value As Integer)
    clr_rng.Interior.Color = RGB(red_value, grn_value, blu_value)
End Sub
```

Which could be called like so:

```
Set_RGB ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G20"), 255, 51, 204
```

or..

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set_RGB ws.Range("G20"), 255, 51, 204
```